# multiple small java-database transactions or one big java-database transaction? which is faster?

Tags: java, mysql, database, performance, jdbc

I have a MySQL table with 140 columns and a txt file with about 80k lines, i.e. 7.5k entries(rows) for the table.

which would be faster?

"insert into myTable (<140 column names>) values (<140 column entries>);"
Shall i enter one whole row at a time(just one database transaction per row, but as there are 140 columns the lone insert statement will be very long)

or

"update myTable set  =  where =...;"
enter a column entry one by one(making many database transactions)

Comment: "I have a MySQL table with 140 columns" ... And then you used the word "faster". Interesting.

Comment: In-memory string operations are several orders of magnitude faster than calling the database. To understand why, see the following: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13975668/1919251

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fewer commits/queries that are ran, the faster it will be. Play around with different chunk sizes.  E.g. insert x number of rows and commit. Repeat until all rows are done.  Much of the performance is dependant on what triggers and indexes are configured on the table.

Comment: Thank you for replying :)
I have a question regarding this solution though.

When i was using multiple transactions, most of my code was doing jdbc work. But now the code will do basic java, i.e. formulating the one big INSERT statement using the data extracted from the txt file.
 
So my question is, will i benefit if i go for this approach or will the excess java work(formulation of the big INSERT statement) take as much time as the multiple database transactions?

Comment: +1 As you have larger and larger transactions, the benefit reduces.  You could get to the point where making it larger is slightly worse.  I would start with 100 or 1000 inserts per transaction.

Comment: All in all, it is 7.5k database transactions + extra java string operations vs. 80k database transactions. What do you have to say about this? which is faster? @PeterLawrey

Comment: If you divide the number of transactions by 10, it could be 5x faster at a guess, but it is much easier for you try it and see. ;)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you to use bulk insert:

```
BULK INSERT List FROM 'c:\Txt.txt' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '","')
```

It's cleaner approach

Comment: Doesn't BULK INSERT take a table lock? Are you sure that's acceptable for Dhruva's application?

Comment: His intention is unclear, if he wants to insert large amount of data from text file to table, above is the cleaner approach

Comment: Thank you for replying :)
I have a question regarding this solution though.

When i was using multiple transactions, most of my code was doing jdbc work. But now the code will do basic java, i.e. formulating the one big INSERT statement using the data extracted from the txt file.
 
So my question is, will i benefit if i go for this approach or will the excess java work(formulation of the big INSERT statement) take as much time as the multiple database transactions?

Comment: @DhruvaJain my suggestion is instead of formatting big insert statement, format your text file in the column format with delimiter (say ,) and execute above statement using JDBC, that would be best way.

Comment: Have a look at this argument.

Making and executing a 140(which will involve many basic java string operations) columns long INSERT statement 7.5 k times(as there are 7.5k rows) VS. making and executing a single-column INSERT statement 80k times?
which would be faster?

Comment: Obviously second one.. @DhruvaJain

Comment: @PradeepSimha, the second option represents the multiple database transactions. As you see, 1st option makes database transactions 7.5k times but does additional java string operations. Whereas, the second option does lesser java string operations and 80k database transactions. Basically, it is 7.5k database transactions + extra java string operations vs. 80k database transactions. What do you have to say about this?

Comment: That's why I have suggested 1)create a file with all string operations done and in required format 2) just use a db connection to update all formatted, manipulated, operated text file into db

Comment: BULK INSERT INTO AnotherTable;
Then update FirstTable from AnotherTable in single transaction.

Answer (score 0):

One big transaction will always be faster than 80k transactions.

What  make you believe that creation of 80k transactions will be faster ?

Comment: Thank you for replying :)
I have a question regarding this solution though.

When i was using multiple transactions, most of my code was doing jdbc work. But now the code will do basic java, i.e. formulating the one big INSERT statement using the data extracted from the txt file.
 
So my question is, will i benefit if i go for this approach or will the excess java work(formulation of the big INSERT statement) take as much time as the multiple database transactions?

Comment: Creating the INSERT statement yourself by parsing a text file in java take less than a millisecond (I know Java is not that fast, but it will be always faster than 80k socket transactions)

Comment: So, you're saying that making a 140(which will involve many basic java string operations) columns long insert statement 7.5 k times(as there are 7.5k rows) is faster than making a single-column INSERT statement 80k times?

Comment: @DhruvaJain Certainly it is. Do you have any evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @DhruvaJain How would 80k one column inserts be equivalent to 7.5K 140 column inserts? The end result is not the same. Also: you are using parametrized queries right and not constructing the insert statement every time?